# Why does in_array() return unexpected / strange results?

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

Why is `in_array()` sometimes behaving so strangely and returns such unexpected results?

Let's have a look at a few examples:

```
$arrayWithTrue = ['Andreas', 'Philipp', true];
$arrayWithNull = [1, 2, 3, null];
$arrayWithMinusOne = [-1];

var_dump(in_array('Gary', $arrayWithTrue)); // returns bool(true)
var_dump(in_array(0, $arrayWithNull)); // returns bool(true)
var_dump(in_array(true, $arrayWithMinusOne)); // returns bool(true)
```

Huh? What's happening here!?

(Some years ago I wondered about this, at first, strange behaviour. I thought it might be useful for some people though, thus I entered this question.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### **Solution (in short):**

Use `in_array()` always with the third parameter *strict* `true`:

```
$arrayWithTrue = ['Andreas', 'Philipp', true];
$arrayWithNull = [1, 2, 3, null];
$arrayWithMinusOne = [-1];

var_dump(in_array('Gary', $arrayWithTrue, true)); // returns bool(false)
var_dump(in_array(0, $arrayWithNull, true)); // returns bool(false)
var_dump(in_array(true, [-1], true)); // returns bool(false)
```

So when you use `in_array()` with `true` as third parameter, the comparison between the searched value and the array is done strictly, meaning `in_array()` works like you would probably expect it.

(The parameter *strict* is also described in the [php.net documentation](http://php.net/in_array).)

### Explanation

Without the parameter *strict* set to true, the comparison between the searched value and each value of the array is done by equality and not by identity. This means that the value's type does not matter and thus PHP converts the values internally to the same data type in order to be able to compare them.

This means that in the first example, the searched value `'Gary'` is converted to a boolean when it's compared with `true`, so it results in the comparison of `true` with `true`, which is obviously `true`.

The same goes with the second array, where `0` is finally compared with `null`, resulting in `true`, even though `0` is obviously not the same as `null` (this can be especially tricky when you work with numbers and / or function results for example, where `null` can express an empty value and not `0`).

The third array then looks really weird, because we check for the value `true` in the array, which only contains `-1`, but `in_array()` still returns `true` for the comparison. In this case the `-1` gets converted to a boolean `true`. So the problem is the same in both directions.

You can find more examples about the comparison problem in PHP (because this is the same as `==` / `===`) in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/6191314).

Unfortunately, the default for the *strict* parameter when calling `in_array()` is... well, yeah, `false`. :-/ PHP and it's typing...

### Consequences

You should really never ever call `in_array()` without the *strict* parameter set to `true`. When you do not have arrays of mixed types and you only check the values with the same type, `in_array()` works as expected. See this example:

```
$arrayWithStrings = ['Andreas', 'Philipp', 'Friedrich'];
var_dump(in_array('Gary', $arrayWithStrings)); // returns bool(false)
```

So at least this works as expected. But in my opinion, it is much easier to just always call `in_array()` with *strict* `true`. (Similiar to the "SQL Injection Problem"... Just always use PDO and prepared statements so you're safe, even though it's a query without variable parameters. You're always safe then.)

### Be careful though

You should definitely call `in_array()` with *strict* `true`. But there is one downside though, I do want to mention (even though it is obvious). You must definitely use the correct types when calling `in_array()` then:

```
$arrayWithNumbers = [1, 2, 3];
var_dump(in_array('1', $arrayWithNumbers, true)); // returns bool(false)
```

But you can just use Type Casting, when you know that you compare numbers:

```
$arrayWithNumbers = [1, 2, 3];
var_dump(in_array((int)'1', $arrayWithNumbers, true)); // returns bool(true)
```

### Bonus

```
// Comparing false with an empty array
var_dump(in_array(false, [[]])); // returns bool(true)
```

Well, yeah... Just use it with *strict* set to `true`. ;-)

Comment: this bonus made my day "var_dump(in_array(false, [[]]))" - good job